# jQuery onclick Add/Remove class of child element

Tags: jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

Here is the HTML:

```
<a id="docLocked" title="Unlock this document" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;"><span class="iconfa-lock"></span></a>
```

When the 'icon' is clicked I need it to remove the class of the span element and then add another class.

Here is what I have but it is not working:

```
jQuery('#docLocked').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('span').removeClass('iconfa-lock');
        jQuery(this).closest('span').addClass('iconfa-unlock');
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Wow. Seven answers virtually the same, within 4 minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not keep it simple:

```
$('#docLocked').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('iconfa-lock iconfa-unlock');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZMNa6/1/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: I like this method as it fixed a bug that I was having after I clicked it one time, it would no longer function trying to click it again to keep locking/unlocking it.

Comment: I'm only glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

closes finds ancestor. You should use .find() instead

try

```
$(this).find('span')
```

Comment: next searching for next element NOT CHILD

Comment: @Krzysiek, you were right. I thought the span was outside the anchor tag. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#docLocked').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('iconfa-lock').addClass('iconfa-unlock');
});
```

`find()` will look withing the element and find the, in this case, child of the `<a>` tag that is a `<span>`.

Notice how you can also chain the removeClass and the addClass since each returns the same elements it was passed.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#docLocked').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('iconfa-lock').addClass('iconfa-unlock');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution , `find()` is what your are looking for :

```
jQuery('#docLocked').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('iconfa-lock').addClass('iconfa-unlock');;

    });
```

Or using `.children()`:

```
jQuery('#docLocked').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).children()[0].removeClass('iconfa-lock').addClass('iconfa-unlock');;

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The « closest » jQuery method progress up the DOM tree, if you want to find a child, you have to use the « children » or the « find » method.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4wjA/2/) that works for this:

```
jQuery('#docLocked span').click(function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass('iconfa-lock').addClass('iconfa-unlock');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **find** in place of **closest**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `href` linking to a different page - which makes no sense here, as you wouldn't notice any class change - it won't work, so you should prevent the default behavior before doing anything else.
Also, you need to change the selector, because `.closest()` will look for a sibling, not a child.

```
jQuery('#docLocked').on('click', function (e) {
    // Stop the default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // Save the href value to be used after (if you need to)
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // Select a span which is within the clicked anchor
    jQuery('span', this).toggleClass('iconfa-lock').toggleClass('iconfa-unlock');

    // Doesn't work on jsFiddle
    // if (href != "")
        //window.location.href = href;
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GLEc2/

Comment: Any reason to use .on('click' rather than .click(function(e) ?

Comment: Just to avoid problems if you decide to add further elements dynamically. There's no harm on doing this way.

Comment: And, from the [API for `click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), `click()` "is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`." So using `on()` saves a little time and is more efficient.